# Turn the two highest values of a pytorch tensor / numpy array to 1 and the others to zero

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have some pytorch tensors (or numpy arrays) and want to turn the two highest numbers to a 1 and every other number to a zero. So this tensor

```
tensor([0.9998, 0.9997, 0.9991, 0.9998, 0.9996, 0.9996, 0.9997, 0.9995],
   dtype=torch.float64)
```

Should become this:

```
tensor([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   dtype=torch.float64)
```

There are some ways to turn the highest number to 1 and the others to 0, but I need the two highest numbers to become 1. Why isn't there a built in function for that? I have a classification problem where I know that two objects belong to class 1. So shouldn't this be a quite common problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `topk`:

```py
x = tensor([0.9998, 0.9997, 0.9991, 0.9998, 0.9996, 0.9996, 0.9997, 0.9995], dtype=torch.float64)

_, idx = x.topk(2)

x.fill_(0)
x[idx] = 1
```